# Trying to create simple servlet but it gives error with the java class. Is anyone know the reason?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [com.marvel.AddServlet]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.marvel.AddServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1634)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.marvel.AddServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1634)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.enter code here

```java
package com.marvel;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
        public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));
            int j = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));
            int k = i + j;
            System.out.println("result is " + k);
            
        }
    }
```

```
Java Resourses 
   src    
     com.marvel    
        AddServlet

WebContent    
   WEB_INF    
       web.xml
```

```xml
web.xml

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>addition</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.marvel.AddServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>addition</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: The message `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.marvel.AddServlet` - means it can't find your `AddServlet` class. How are you deploying your servlet?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yeah, but I do not know why it cannot find my class. I am using 'tomcat' and it is installed on my machine. I am using it with 'Eclipse java EE version'. I am using web.xml file to deploy my Servlet.